# Что такое «псевдоклассы» в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

[Читая статью](https://learn.javascript.ru/native-prototypes#%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-javascript) наткнулся на определение классов в JavaScript: `«Псевдоклассом» или, более коротко, «классом», называют функцию-конструктор вместе с её prototype. Такой способ объявления классов называют «прототипным стилем ООП».` Вопрос в том, почему написали `«Псевдоклассом»`. Это потому что функция - конструктор является жалкой пародией на класс? Просто до этого в статьях называли всегда классом, а тут пригнобили, и я подумал, что что - то упустил.

Я знаю что добавили в EcmaScript 6 добавили полноценные [Классы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) если их так можно назвать, ибо это мой первый язык.

Comment: потому что используется другой, менее распространенный, подход к ооп. Чтобы у новичков при этом было хоть что-то знакомое - решили называть классами, но так как к классам в привычном понимании это слабо относится решили добавить приставку _псевдо_

Comment: Да и в любом случае, здесь больше вопрос терминологии.